# Finding arrays where the sum is 0 mod n

Tags: algorithm

There are arrays of length m where all entries are positive(>= 0)  integers. I want the sum of the entries to be 0 mod n.

I want a list of all such arrays where the sum of the squares of the entries are smaller than k.

How do I do this? I can not think of a way that finds all such arrays, just some of them.

I can show what I've written in python, but my method is flawed and I need to start from scratch so I will not show it unless requested upon.

Comment: http://php.net/foreach http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only think of a quite brute force solution right now. Let me give a example with real numbers. Let m = 4, n = 5 and k = 25. Therefore, what you would have, was to iterate over all the array and for each position, test all the numbers from 1 to a given range *u*.
For the calculation of this *u*, I thought about this. In this worst case, you will have something like:

[1 1 1 u]

This means that 3 + u**2 must be smaller than k. Therefore, I use *u* as int(sqrt(k - (m-1))).

```
from math import sqrt

array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
comb = [0 for i in range(m)]
u = int(sqrt(k-m+1))

all_combs(comb, 0, 0, 0)

def all_combs(comb, pos, sum, square_sum):
    global n, m, u, k

    if (square_sum > k):
        # Invalid case
        return
    if (pos == m):
        if (sum % n == 0):
            print comb
        return

    for i in range(1,u+1):
        comb[pos] = i
        all_combs(comb, pos + 1, sum + i, sum_square + i**2)
```

Is it clear?

Comment: 1: "array" is not used as far as i can see
2: the lost entry in comp is incorrect, it isn't always 0 mod n and the square sum is too large.

Answer (score 0):

Three observations that will help you are the following:

1. The constraints on the array are independent of the order of the elements of the array. Therefore assume `a_0 <= a_1 <= ... <= a_m-1`.
2. An array `[a_0,...,a_m-1]` of nonnegative integers has sum `0 mod n` if and only if `-a_m-1 = a0 + ... + a_m-2 mod n`. Therefore the first `m-1` entries are free but the final entry is fixed.
3. The condition `a_0^2 + ... + a_m-1^2 < k` bounds the size of the entries. Therefore the loops are finite.

A solution might go something like this:

```
array := [0,...,0];
sqsum := sum_{j=0..m-1} array[j]^2;
for i := m-2...1 do {
  array[i]++;
  for j from i+1 to m-2 do
    array[j] := array[i];
  L := sum_{j=0..m-2} array[j] mod n;
  array[m-1] := n-L;
  sqsum := sum_{j=0..m-1} array[j]^2;
  while sqsum < k do {
    print(array);
    sqsum := sqsum + 2*array[m-1]n+n^2;
    array[m-1] := array[m-1]+n;
  }
}
```